# RadEditor dot spot looks

Tags: radeditor

I'm writing a news site, I've used RadEditor after a while it's broken, it seems weird, the font field looks dot.

As it appears in the picture. I can't write posts. Can you help me. good work.
[enter image description here](http://www.ozgengayrimenkul.net/editor.jpg)

Comment: please rewrite your question in English, this is an English site

Comment: oh.. sory..
edit now

Answer (score 0):

To fix the appearance problem enable the telerik:RadStyleSheetManager CDN:

```
<telerik:RadStyleSheetManager
    ID="RadStyleSheetManager1"
    runat="server"
    CdnSettings-TelerikCdn="Enabled" />
```